# reach local WildFly server over LAN

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, network-programming, wildfly

So my firewall is OFF and my `standalone.xml` contains

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
          <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:192.168.56.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Running `netstat` gives

```
C:\Users\Ram>netstat -an | find "8080"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50200        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
```

Running `telnet` from another computer connected to the network

```
C:\Users\Rami>telnet 192.168.56.1 8080
Connecting To 192.168.56.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8080
: Connect failed
```

I can reach the server homepage typing `http://192.168.56.1:8080/` on the computer that has the server started on but not from any other device connected to my local home network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration looks fine, I assume that there is some other Windows /network configuration besides the firewall setting preventing your access.

Try `telnet hostname port` from your client to your server to check if port is accessible ([see this SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/128775/how-to-discover-if-a-specific-address-port-is-reachable)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will run the `telnet` command tonight and see the result. So what if it doesn't establish a connection?

Comment: @RaMi It means that there is still some issue within your local network, e.g. your router doesn't let traffic through or does not forward the port.
Note: telnet might not be installed and you have to activate it.

Comment: too bad .. it failed. What should i check next ?

Comment: Are you certain that your IP address is `192.168.56.1`? It is unusual to see a desktop with x.x.x.1 address.

Comment: You're my man !! I was actually wondering because all my devices were always something like `xxx.xxx.0.xx`. i looked back again and `192.168.56.1` was the IP assigned to virtual box ! Thanks a lot Geziefer and Steve C